# Comparing first column with second column and taking out the values which are not uniq in second column in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

Comparing first column with second column and taking out the values which are not uniq in second column in shell script.

**sample input :**

```
58811051802414,50064179170,0000,TEREAE,20160630,TESTIIII,,,,20130628T04:30:06

58811051802414,50064179170,0000,TEREAE,20160630,TESTIIII,,,,20130628T04:30:06

70128031244580,50064178465,1000,TEREAE,20160630,TESTIIII,,,,20130628T04:30:06

70128031244580,50064178255,1000,TEREAE,20160630,TESTIIII,,,,20130628T04:30:06
```

**desired output :**

```
58811051802414,50064179170,0000,TEREAE,20160630,TESTIIII,,,,20130628T04:30:06

70128031244580,50064178465,1000,TEREAE,20160630,TESTIIII,,,,20130628T04:30:06

70128031244580,50064178255,1000,TEREAE,20160630,TESTIIII,,,,20130628T04:30:06
```

We need to see first column value which are uniq and compare with second column of a same file ,if uniq print the value , we need to omit duplicates and print only the uniq value.

**second Modification.**

```
70128031244580,50064178465,1000,TEREAE,20160630,TESTIIII,,,,20130628T04:30:06

70128031244580,50064178255,1000,TEREAE,20160630,TESTIIII,,,,20130628T04:30:06
```

These two first columns are having different second columns we need to print this as

```
70128031244580,Found 2 different values.
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F, '!a[$1,$2]++' file

58811051802414,50064179170,0000,TEREAE,20160630,TESTIIII,,,,20130628T04:30:06
70128031244580,50064178465,1000,TEREAE,20160630,TESTIIII,,,,20130628T04:30:06
70128031244580,50064178255,1000,TEREAE,20160630,TESTIIII,,,,20130628T04:30:06
```

piping this to the second script

```
$ awk -F, '!a[$1,$2]++' file | 
  awk -F, '{a[$1]++} END{for(k in a) if(a[k]>1) print k, "Found " a[k] " values"}'

70128031244580 Found 2 values
```